# Meteor/React: Redirect outside of component as callback of AccountsTemplates.logout()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, browser-history, meteor-useraccounts

I'm trying to integrate the **meteor-useraccounts** package with *React* in my Meteor app. I've come pretty far, but am struggling to implement a `history.push()` or equivalent as a callback function to the `AccountsTemplate.logout()` - the latter being the built in way of logging out a user.

The configuration of the callback func is done this way:

```
AccountsTemplates.configure({
    onLogoutHook: myLogoutFunc
})
```

But I can't do this within a "class" of React.Component. So I need to define callback function that uses the browser history, but is outside of any Components scope, I guess.

For the case of hitting a ***Sign In/Out* *button***, I found a solution as follows:

```
class LogInOutButton extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            loggedIn: Meteor.userId() ? true : false,
            redirect: false
        }

        this.redirectToSignIn = this.redirectToSignIn.bind(this);

        window.logInOutButton = this;
    }

    redirectToSignIn() {
        if (!this.state.loggedIn && document.location.pathname !== "/signIn")
            this.setState({redirect: <Redirect to="/signIn" />});
    }

    render() {
        const { redirect } = this.state
        return (
            <li className="nav-item">
                {redirect}
                <a className="nav-link" href="#"
                    onClick={Meteor.userId() ? AccountsTemplates.logout : this.redirectToSignIn}>
                    {Meteor.userId() ? "Sign Out" : "Sign In"}
                </a>
            </li>
        )
    }
}
```

As you can see I, for example, tried calling the `redirectToSignIn()` method from outside by making it a member of the global **window** object. Doesn't feel right and doesn't work either:

```
var myLogoutFunc = () =>
    window.logInOutButton.redirectToSignIn();
```

I also tried the following approach:

```
var myLogoutFunc = withRouter(({history}) => 
    <div onLoad={history.push="/signIn"}>
    </div>
)
```

However, this won't work, because `withRouter` needs a Component as param, if I got it right? At least this is how I try to explain the following error:

```
Exception in delivering result of invoking 'logout': TypeError: "props is undefined"
```

After reading this in the `withRouter` module:

```
var withRouter = function withRouter(Component) {
  var C = function C(props) {
     ...
```

How would you solve this?

Comment: so you want to redirect user to login page after user logged out? why don't you use `Meteor.logout()` then redirect with `props.history`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do. It is recommended by the authors of meteor-useraccounts package to use AccountsTemplates.logout() instead. If you tell me, that it's safe, that would be an option.

Comment: never use meteor-useraccounts before, if you fully use their templates to render logout/login button then you should use `AccountsTemplates.logout()` instead.

Comment: Meteor.logout() is pretty safe i believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just trying to redirect the user to a landing page when they log out, are logged out or when they come to the app/site while not logged in? I often do this a few different ways depending on the complexity of my app/routes/permissions/etc.

I tend to use iron:router and Blaze, not React, but I think the most straightforward solution is easy to translate. I drop this somewhere at the top level of my client-side code:

```
Tracker.autorun(function() {
    const userDoc = Meteor.user();
    const loggingIn = Meteor.loggingIn();

    if(!userDoc && !loggingIn) {
        Router.go('/'); // Or comparable redirect command
    }
});
```

On page load:
If the `userDoc` is not defined (meaning the user is not logged in successfully) and `loggingIn` is not true (meaning Meteor is not in the process of logging a user in on page load), we'll redirect the user to the home page.

On log out: 
Since `userDoc` and `loggingIn` are both reactive data sources, this `autorun` function will rerun any time either of those variables change. So, when the user logs out by any means, `userDoc` will cease to be defined, the conditional will resolve to `true` and it'll redirect the user to the home page.

On log in:
If a logged-out user logs in or begins to log in, nothing will happen. The function will re-run, but forcing an automatic redirect any time the `userDoc` or `loggingIn` variable change can become more complicated.

Comment: This is so simple and straight forward, but I was stuck in my mind box. I cannot apply this directly, as I abandonded the whole approach, but I've definitely learned.

Comment: Cool! Learning is good. More than one way to pet a cat, obviously, but thanks for circling back and acknowledging my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I abandoned the idea of using a package for creating an UI for the account system.

The package **meteor-useraccounts** was made for Blaze, and although in the official Meteor docs they encourage wrapping the `{{> atForm }}` template which renders the forms for Sign In, Sign Up, etc. into a React.Component, I found it to cause incompatibilities especially with handling the routes. (I had used the package `gadicc:blaze-react-component` for wrapping.)
In the end I found myself trying to understand this black box, that was made up of multiple layers, incl. another one for bootstrap4 pre-styling. For example I also couldn't make the email verification work.

So I decided to dump it all, and started building the whole UI and logic myself on top of the Meteor [Accounts](https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html) and Meteor [Passwords API](https://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html).

Now redirecting is darn simple, because I can do it within my own React.Component. The only thing you need to do is `import { withRouter } from 'react-router';`, then  `export default withRouter(LogInOutButton);` and finally you can use `this.props.history.push("/signIn")` to redirect:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

class LogInOutButton extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            loggedIn: Meteor.userId() ? true : false,
        }

        this.redirectToSignIn = this.redirectToSignIn.bind(this);
    }

    redirectToSignIn() {
        if (this.state.loggedIn)
            Meteor.logout()
        if (document.location.pathname !== "/signIn")
            this.props.history.push("/signIn")
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <li className="nav-item">
                <a className="nav-link" href="#"
                    onClick={this.redirectToSignIn}>
                    {Meteor.userId() ? "Sign Out" : "Sign In"}
                </a>
            </li>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(LogInOutButton);
```

---

**PS:** *(Just my opinion)* Of course there a things to solve when building your own UI/Logic for the account system. For example form validation. (I decided to built on top of the HTML5 validation, but add my own visual feedback with [bootstrap4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/forms/#validation).)

I guess in the case of Meteor **and** React there is simply no working package at the moment. I tried them all, believe me. They were all a pain in the ass (when trying to integrate them with React) or not customizable enough. If I'd spent the time to build my own from the start, I'd long be finished by now. And the great thing about doing it yourself is, you know how it works and can easily refine and reuse it later.

It also helps keep dependencies low, which I find crucial, because the Meteor project has been progressing and changing rapidly in the last years. It's easier to keep your project up to date, when you know what you did.

Comment: @Mikkel Yes, but had problems. The docs are out of date, and I did not find a way to make it work with React Router v4, which is quite different. Did you have success?

Comment: I originally hacked it for my own purposes a while ago, but I notice that one of the devs pitched it out in favour of a custom solution like you :)